# SQL Server 2014 Install Failed with The computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm attempting to install SQL Sever 2014 newly installed Windows Sever 2012 R2 Standard edition OS.  During the GUI portion of the installation it fails with the following error:

> There was an error generating the XML document.

Looking at the detail.txt files I see the following error:

> (01) 2015-09-14 19:32:31 Slp:             Message:  (01) 2015-09-14
>   19:32:31 Slp:                         The requested operation cannot
>   be completed. The computer must be trusted for delegation and the
>   current user account must be configured to allow delegation. (01)
>   2015-09-14 19:32:31 Slp:                          (01) 2015-09-14
>   19:32:31 Slp:             HResult : 0x80090345 (01) 2015-09-14
>   19:32:31 Slp:             Stack:  (01) 2015-09-14 19:32:31 Slp:
>   at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData,
>   Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope) (01) 2015-09-14
>   19:32:31 Slp:                         at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Common.SqlSecureString.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
>   (01) 2015-09-14 19:32:31 Slp:                         at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteSerializable(IXmlSerializable
>   serializable, String name, String ns, Boolean isNullable, Boolean
>   wrapped) (01) 2015-09-14 19:32:31 Slp:                         at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAgentConfigurationPublic.Write6_AgentConfigurationPublic(String
>   n, String ns, AgentConfigurationPublic o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean
>   needType) (01) 2015-09-14 19:32:31 Slp:                         at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAgentConfigurationPublic.Write7_AgentConfigurationPublic(Object
>   o)

I've attempted to do the install as administrator same issue either way.

Comment: Are you running it as a domain user?

Comment: I'm installing from my domain account that is in the local administrators group.

Comment: Do you have KB2918614 installed? Make sure to download the latest version of the installer.

Comment: @BartDeVos No I don't have that installed.  I did notice some missing updates so I'm applying those as a precaution.

Comment: @BartDeVos I ran all remaining windows updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by creating a local account adding that account to the administrators account.  I think this might have been a domain issue as this server is in a different domain than my own.  A local account worked to get the installation to complete.

[Used this link for the answer:](https://web.archive.org/web/20200926114646/http://geekswithblogs.net/vitus/archive/2009/09/26/workaround-for-sql-2008-express-installation-error-0x84b10001.aspx)